# How to translate this Objective-C Code into Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new to Swift and I am trying to convert this line of code from Objective-C to Swift. Here's the objective-c code:

First off, the objective C Code for the terms and locations are this:

```
NSString *term = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"term"] ?: defaultTerm;
NSString *location = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"location"] ?: defaultLocation;
```

I translated this into this swift (which i'm not sure how to account for the ?: defaultTerm)

```
    var term: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("term");
    var location: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("location");
    var ApiSample:YPAPISample = YPAPISample();
```

And this is the query in Objective-C:
    [APISample queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm:term location:location completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *topBusinessJSON, NSError *error) {

[image: Parameters]

When I type my swift code, it comes out like this

```
APISample.queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm(term, location: location) { (topBusinessJSON, error) -> Void in
        code
    }
```

I tried removing the -> and void but it just doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: There is no reason to remove the -> Void. If you leave it in, do you have any problems?

Comment: So it'd be:
var term: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("term") ?? defaultTerm?

Comment: Yes, it does not compile

Comment: "It does not compile" gives a lot of information. Posting an exact error message would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
// cast the results that come back from UserDefaults

var term: String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("term") as? String
var location: String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("location") as? String


APISample.queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm(term, location: location, completionHandler: { (topBusinessJSON: [NSObject: AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        //code
    })
```

Comment: "Cannot invoke 'queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject?, location: ANyObject?, completionHandler:(NSDictionary!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Comment: It looks like it might be a problem with the parameters you are passing in. What pameters is it expecting for location and term. Are the just NSObjects?

Comment: Can you show me the method declaration of `queryTopBusinessInfoForTerm` I want to see what parameters it is expecting. You may have to cast your results from `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83825/discussion-between-villy393-and-varun-varahabotla).